# Query Top 5 categories with the most content, return 5 content from each category and join associaled user name with content with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am very new to laravel and having a hard time with this...

I have 3 tables

category:

```
id,
name,
...;
```

video:

```
id,
category_id,
user_id,
..;
```

User:

```
id
```

in the category model i created a hasmany relationship with video:

```
public function video()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Video')->where('isLive', 1);
}
```

And in video model a  belongsTo relationship with category

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

in categories controller i am getting my data by running the following query

```
 public function index()
{
    $data = \App\Category::where('is_active', 1)
                ->with('video')
                ->paginate(15);
}
```

My main issue is how to join the username of each video with the result

the minor issue is getting top 5 categories with most videos

Comment: Did you create relation to user for Video Model?

Comment: yes i did but i don't know how to link the queries to get the username for each video

Comment: please edit and  add it to your question to get better answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Top 5 categories having most videos :

```
$top5Cat = Category::withCount('video')->orderBy('video_count', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

You can then add an eager loading to get 5 videos of those :

```
$top5CatWithVideos = Category::withCount('video')->with(['video' => function($q){
    return $q->take(5);
}])->orderBy('video_count', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

A suggestion to update relation function from `video` to `videos` as its `hasMany`

Now adding user of each video :

```
$top5CatWithVideos = Category::withCount('video')->with(['video' => function($q){
        return $q->take(5);
}, 'video.user'])->->orderBy('video_count', 'desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

Comment: thanks, the issue is only half solved i just need a way to include the username of each user for each video.

Comment: I have added the user relation also in eager loading for a video. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most beautiful query I've written, but you can do it with SQL, the reason to use IN(subquery(subquery())) is to be able to use LIMIT

```
SELECT
    b.*,
    u.username
FROM
    (
        (SELECT video.* FROM video
        WHERE video.category_id IN(
                SELECT a.category_id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT category_id FROM video GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1
                    ) as a
            )
        LIMIT 5)
        UNION (SELECT video.* FROM video 
        WHERE video.category_id IN(
                SELECT a.category_id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT category_id FROM video GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1,1
                    ) as a
            )
        LIMIT 5)
        UNION (SELECT video.* FROM video 
        WHERE video.category_id IN(
                SELECT a.category_id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT category_id FROM video GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 2,1
                    ) as a
            )
        LIMIT 5)
        UNION (SELECT video.* FROM video 
        WHERE video.category_id IN(
                SELECT a.category_id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT category_id FROM video GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 3,1
                    ) as a
            )
        LIMIT 5)
        UNION (SELECT video.* FROM video 
        WHERE video.category_id IN(
                SELECT a.category_id
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT category_id FROM video GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 4,1
                    ) as a
            )
        LIMIT 5)
    ) as b
JOIN user u ON
    u.id = b.user_id
```

After that I think you do something like this in laravel:

```
$videos = DB::select($aboveQuery);
```